# Linked list traversal skips first element

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have a C program to insert elements at the beginning of a linked list but when I try to print the elements it always skips the first element. Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong in my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>


void PrintElements();
void InsertElement(int x);

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* HEAD;
struct node* temp;
struct node* temp1;


void PrintElements()
{
    temp1=HEAD;
    while(temp1->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\r Data %d\n\r",temp1->data);
        printf("\n\r Address %x\n\r",temp1->next);
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
}

void InsertElement(int x)
{
    struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=HEAD;
    HEAD=temp;

}

int main()
{

    int i, x;
    int n;   //n stores the number of elements to be added to the linked list
    HEAD=NULL; //Assigning HEAD to null when there are no elements in the list
    printf("Enter the number of elements\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n\rEnter the number");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        InsertElement(x);
        PrintElements();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I changed the following line

```
while(temp1->next!=NULL)
```

to

```
while(temp1!=NULL)
```

the program works correctly but I am still not able to understand why.

Comment: Because in one you check a pointer to an element, and in the other you check the pointer to the _next_ element, i.e. you’re terminating with different conditions. Try with longer lists and you’ll see what happens. PS: global variables are evil.

Comment: If you check with `while(temp1->next!=NULL)`, then you will always skip the first element.

Comment: The answer to your second question after the change is: What happens when you insert your first node? What is the value for `HEAD` at that moment? (hint: `NULL`). Since you always insert at the beginning of the list, your `first` node will always be the *last* node printed. When printing the *last* node, what is the value of `node->next`? (it is `NULL`). If you use `while(temp1->next!=NULL)` when you reach the last node (first value) `temp1->next == NULL`, so the loop terminates leaving the last node (first value) unprinted. Making the suggested change eliminates that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you describe can be fixed by changing the controlling expression in your `PrintElements()` function to `temp1 != NULL`. This way, if `temp1` points to a node, the `data` and `next` fields are printed, and the loop continues until there are no more nodes. When iterating over a linked list, it usually seems to confuse things when you look at the next node to decide what you will do with the current node. But there are other problems with this code.

First, it would be much better to declare the `struct` pointers in `main()` and pass them to the functions, instead of declaring them as global variables. You should check the return values of the functions that you call whenever possible. You should check `scanf()` to make sure that the input is as expected; this also provides a way to control the input loop, removing the need for the user to explicitly enter a count before inputting data. You should also check the value returned by calls to `malloc()` to catch allocation errors. Such an allocation error in your code would lead to undefined behavior when `temp` is dereferenced in the very next line.

You should `free` all memory allocations, one `free()` for each call to `malloc()`. When you print the address of the `next` node in the list in the function `PrintElements()`, you invoke undefined behavior. To print the value of a pointer, you should use the `%p` format specifier, and you must cast the pointer to `(void *)`. Finally, there is no need to `#include <malloc.h>`; `stdlib.h` takes care of what you need.

Here is a modified version of your code that implements the suggested changes. Note that in the event of an allocation error, a message is printed to `stderr`, and the program `exit`s. The call to `malloc()` has been simplified: there is no reason to cast the result of `malloc()` in C, and it is better to use the name of the pointer to which you are assigning the memory in place of an explicit type in the argument given to `malloc()`. The `new_node` is returned to the calling function, where the pointer to the `head` of the list is reassigned to point to the `new_node`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void print_elements(struct node *start);
struct node * insert_element(int x, struct node *head);


int main(void)
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* curr = NULL;
    int x;

    /* Read data into linked list */
    printf("Enter the first integer (q to quit): ");
    while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
        head = insert_element(x, head);
        print_elements(head);
        printf("Enter another integer (q to quit): ");
    }

    /* Free allocated memory */
    while (head) {
        curr = head;
        head = curr->next;
        free(curr);
    }

    return 0;
}

void print_elements(struct node *curr)
{
    while(curr) {
        printf("   Data: %d\n",curr->data);
        printf("Address: %p\n\n",(void *) curr->next);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

struct node * insert_element(int x, struct node *head)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));

    if (new_node == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation error in function insert_element()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_node->data = x;
    new_node->next = head;

    return new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`while(temp1->next!=NULL)`

Change this to

`while(temp1 != NULL)`

And it should work fine.

**Reason**: I think it does not prints the first element you input.

Example: Input: `1 2 3`

Linked list formed as : `3 -> 2 -> 1 -> NULL`
Notation used: Every number is the `data`, and the arrow shows the pointer `next`.

Then when you start the loop, For each iteration:

- `temp1` points to address of `3`
- `temp1 -> next != NULL` (true as `temp1 -> next` points to address of `2`)
- Prints `3` and `temp1` now points to address of `2`
- `temp1 -> next != NULL` (true as `temp1 -> next` points to address of `1`)
- Prints `2` and `temp1` now points to address of `1`
- `temp1 -> next != NULL` This becomes **False** as `temp1` points to address of `1` and `temp1 -> next` is NULL.

So we never go inside the loop to print `1`.

So the correct thing is to use `temp1 != NULL` as this will eliminate the above bug.

Comment: Good explaination !! From which JNV you are ??

Comment: What's a JNV, I have no idea.