# Why is my linked list when being traversed skipping the first node?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am learning C and I am currently learning about dynamic memory allocation and linked lists and I ran into a problem. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404995/linked-list-traversal-skips-first-element) and followed the answer. However my program is still skipping my first node when being printed out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct record
{
  int id;
  char name[257];
  float age;
  struct record *next;
};

int main(void)
{

  int i = 1;
  struct record *firstrecord = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
  firstrecord->id = 1000;
  char firstname[] = "John Doe";
  memcpy(firstrecord->name, firstname,strlen(firstname) + 1);
  firstrecord->age = 24.5;
  firstrecord->next = NULL;

  struct record *mostrecentlycreated = firstrecord;

  int iyes = 1;
  char cyes;
  int yes = 1;
  while (yes == iyes)
  {
    
      // build next node
      mostrecentlycreated->next = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
      // change data in new record
      int newid;
      char newname[257];
      char temp;
      float newage;
      char cnewage[257];
    
      printf("Enter the name: ");
      fgets(newname,257,stdin);
    
      newid = 1000 + i;

      printf("Enter the person's age: ");
      fgets(cnewage,257,stdin);
      newage = atof(cnewage);
    
      mostrecentlycreated->id = newid;
      memcpy(mostrecentlycreated->name,newname,strlen(newname) + 1);
      mostrecentlycreated->age = newage;
      mostrecentlycreated = mostrecentlycreated->next;
      mostrecentlycreated->next = NULL;


      i++;
      // decide whether or not to keep going
      printf("Do you wish to continue? 1\\0 ");
      
      fgets(&cyes,1,stdin);
      iyes = atoi(&cyes);
    
    
      scanf("%c",&temp);
    
  }
  struct record *traverse = firstrecord;
  while (traverse != NULL)
  {
    printf("Employee id is %i; Employee Name is %s; Employee Age is %f\n",traverse->id,traverse->name,traverse->age);
    traverse = traverse->next;
  }

  free(firstrecord);
  free(mostrecentlycreated);
  return 0;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
Enter the name: john doe
Enter the person's age: 23
Do you wish to continue? 1\0 0
Employee id is 1001; Employee Name is john doe
; Employee Age is 23.000000
Employee id is 0; Employee Name is ; Employee Age is 0.000000
```

Why does it not print out the first person?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your output does show it outputting the first person you entered.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant that I wanted my program to print out the data contained in 'firstrecord' variable before printing out the dynamically allocated ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your first node, your loop is creating a new node on each iteration, but it is assigning the user's input to the *previous* node in the list, not the *current* node being added to the list.  So, on the 1st iteration, you are overwriting the 1st node's data, and then appending a 2nd empty node.  Then on the 2nd iteration, you are overwriting the 2nd node's data, and appending a blank 3rd node. And so on.

Try this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct record
{
  int id;
  char name[257];
  float age;
  struct record *next;
};

int main(void)
{
  int i = 1;

  struct record *firstrecord = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
  firstrecord->id = 1000;
  strncpy(firstrecord->name, "John Doe", 257);
  firstrecord->age = 24.5;
  firstrecord->next = NULL;

  struct record *mostrecentlycreated = firstrecord;

  const int cyes = 1;
  int iyes = 1;

  while (iyes == cyes)
  {    
      // build next node
      struct record *newrecord = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record));

      // change data in new record    
      newrecord->id = 1000 + i;

      printf("Enter the name: ");
      fgets(newrecord->name, 257, stdin);
    
      printf("Enter the person's age: ");
      scanf("%f", &(newrecord->age));
    
      newrecord->next = NULL;

      mostrecentlycreated = newrecord;

      ++i;

      // decide whether or not to keep going
      printf("Do you wish to continue? 1\\0 ");
      scanf("%d", &iyes);
  }

  struct record *traverse = firstrecord;
  while (traverse != NULL)
  {
    printf("Employee id is %i; Employee Name is %s; Employee Age is %f\n", traverse->id, traverse->name, traverse->age);
    traverse = traverse->next;
  }

  traverse = firstrecord;
  while (traverse != NULL)
  {
    struct record *nextrecord = traverse->next;
    free(traverse);
    traverse = nextrecord;
  }

  return 0;
}
```